# Comparar dois campos entre tabelas diferentes

Tags: php, sql

Estou com um grande problema. É o seguinte tenho o Script abaixo:

```
<?php
$contarperfilclientecontar = "0";
$sqlxml = "SELECT id
                  ,vvenda
             FROM imoveis
            WHERE cod = '1042'
              AND status = '2'
          ";
$rsqlxml = mysql_query($sqlxml) or die("Banco XML não abre!");

while ($rowxml = mysql_fetch_array($rsqlxml))
    {
    $vartestevalor = $rowxml['vvenda'];
    $sqlxmlcliente = "SELECT id
                        FROM clientes
                       WHERE cliente = '1042'
                         AND disponibilidade < '$vartestevalor'
                     ";
    $rsqlxmlcliente = mysql_query($sqlxmlcliente) or die("Banco XML não abre!");
    while ($rowxmlcliente = mysql_fetch_array($rsqlxmlcliente))
        {
        $contarperfilclientecontar = $contarperfilclientecontar + 1;
        }
    }
```

Minha intenção é que a tabela `IMOVEIS` verifique todos os imoveis com o campo `VVENDA` que tenham valores `MENORES` que o campo `DISPONIBILIDADE` da tabela cliente e liste o número de registros encontrados.

Só que os números não batem!

Alguém pode me ajudar neste mistério?

Answer (score 2):

Acho que dá para matar tudo em uma *query* só:

```
SELECT imoveis.id
      ,imoveis.vvenda
  FROM imoveis
  LEFT JOIN clientes
    ON clientes.cliente = imoveis.cod
 WHERE imoveis.cod = '1042'
   AND imoveis.status = '2'
   AND clientes.disponibilidade >= imoveis.vvenda
```

Answer (score 0):

Usando a query do @NilsonUehara, apenas para "listar o número de registros encontrados"

```
SELECT imoveis.id,
       imoveis.vvenda,
       count(*) total
  FROM imoveis
  LEFT JOIN clientes
    ON clientes.cliente = imoveis.cod
 WHERE imoveis.cod = '1042'
   AND imoveis.status = '2'
   AND clientes.disponibilidade >= imoveis.vvenda
 GROUP BY imoveis.id,
          imoveis.vvenda
```